# Novel about aliens putting teens through tasks to live on their planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult

A few years ago I read a book about a teen girl going to their high school gym and completing these tests to see if they were eligible to get into this program/spaceship. Earth was gonna be destroyed soon by a meteor or asteroid, so the aliens came to rescue and rehabilitate any eligible humans (meaning no old people or really young people). Colors like yellow and red had a big factor into this book. I remember a kid with an affliction made it into program? The program was like a training period on the spaceship. The “aliens” had lived on earth before or something, and they had “kohl” eyeliner that they wore in solidarity to the male lead, who was also a romance option for the main character.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Can you be more specific about the approximate year you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you remember the cover art?

Comment: It was a physical book, the first book cover was yellow. I read it in 2016.

Comment: @elise How sure are you that you read it 2016? I thought this could be "What Goes Up" by Katie Kennedy, but that was released in 2017 (and didn't have a yellow cover).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like Qualify (The Atlantis Grail Book 1)

> You have two options. You die, or you Qualify.
>
> The year is 2047. An extinction-level asteroid is hurtling toward Earth, and the descendants of ancient Atlantis have returned from the stars in their silver ships to offer humanity help.
>
> But there’s a catch.
>
> They can only take a tiny percent of the Earth’s population back to the colony planet Atlantis. And in order to be chosen, you must be a teen, you must be bright, talented, and athletic, and you must Qualify.
>
> Sixteen-year-old Gwenevere Lark is determined not only to Qualify but to rescue her entire family.
>
> Because there’s a loophole.
>
> If you are good enough to Qualify, you are eligible to compete in the brutal games of the Atlantis Grail, which grants all winners the laurels, high tech luxuries, and full privileges of Atlantis Citizenship. And if you are in the Top Ten, then all your wildest wishes are granted… Such as curing your mother’s cancer.

Comment: Hi. Could you explain how this matches the description given in the question?

Comment: The request was : A few years ago I read a book about a teen girl going to their high school gym and completing these tests to see if they were eligible to get into this program/spaceship. Earth was gonna be destroyed soon by a meteor.  My suggestion : The year is 2047. An extinction-level asteroid is hurtling toward Earth, and the descendants of ancient Atlantis have returned from the stars in their silver ships to offer humanity help.  This is my first attempt to help, and the match seems good. Did I do something wrong?